# Inline Javascript vs External - Is one more secure than the other?

Tags: javascript

A question that I've wondered about every now and again over the years but never really bothered to find a definitive answer to.

We know it's possible to manipulate both inline and external scripts via the console, but are there any small security benefits of one over the other?

Is it a bit harder to manipulate one of them or are they both equally vulnerable?

Comment: To the browser, they’re all JavaScript. One is not safer than the other. Browser dev tools allows you to intercept, pause, debug, and modify JS as you wish—no matter if they’re inlined or not.

Comment: That's what I've always assumed but never actually asked the question.

Comment: What the browser dev tools can do has absolutely nothing to do with security?

Comment: @spice while inline JavaScript may execute faster, it is probably a safer bet to use external JavaScript files.  If you modify a page that includes external JavaScript files you may feel secure about not accidentally tampering/altering the JavaScript.

Comment: @Bergi Tell that to a website that isn't properly verifying ajax submitted content server side.

Comment: @spice Not verifying request contents serverside is a server security problem, it has nothing to do with the devtools.

Comment: If you are the only one have control on external js, its better i presume. easily cacheable. Sometimes you might not need your .html file cached.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Issues With Inline JavaScript**

The main disadvantage of inline JavaScript is the potential of [Cross-site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). Essentially, a trusted website can **unintentionally render code** (in this case JavaScript) that can perform any number malicious acts. A simple example of an inline JavaScript security issue can be found [here](https://glebbahmutov.com/disable-inline-javascript-tutorial/).

---

**Content Security Policies**

When JavaScript is externalized, you can establish a `Content Security Policy` that trusts external JavaScript that is loaded from your website (and other websites if needed) and block all inline JavaScript from executing. Essentially, you are establishing that all of your externally loaded resources are safe, and that if by chance any JavaScript tries to execute inline, then block the attempt.

---

**Additional Steps**

It should be noted, however, that safeguards should be established as a first line of defense to **"clean" incoming and outgoing text**. It should be assumed that any user input, incoming or outgoing, *could* be malicious. Plan accordingly.

The following links have more information:

- [Content Security Policies](https://content-security-policy.com/).
- [Disabling inline JavaScript for security](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/disable-inline-javascript-for-security/)

Comment: So the security benefit comes from using CSP, not from using JavaScript one way or the other.

Comment: Correct. The JavaScript itself is not more secure externally versus internally loaded. Choosing to use inline JavaScript may indirectly be less secure due to inability to effectively use a CSP. Remembering that all choices today could affect the ability to secure your website tomorrow.